# Janus Grid: setting a value in the parent row for a column that is grouped sets child rows to Nothing

Tags: vb.net, grid, group-by, janus

Suppose i have a Janus grid, which has two columns and the rows are organized in a hierarchical order i.e. parent and child rows. One of the columns in the grid is grouped (by dragging the column in the group by box above the grid). I have a cell-changed event that is fired when a cell content is changed. I do this in the cell-changed event:

```
Dim grid as GridEx = e.Column.GridEx 'e is of type ColumnActionEventArgs
Dim value as Object = grid.GetValue(e.Column)
Dim row as GridEXRow = grid.GetRow 'This is the parent row which has 2 child rows for example
...
Dim drCurrent As DataRow = CType(row.DataRow(), DataRowView).Row
drCurrent.Item(e.Column.DataMember) = value 'set the parent row column value
```

If i change the value, in a parent row, of the grouped column then the child rows are set to `Nothing`. After the last line in the above snippet, child rows of `row` are set to `Nothing`. On the other hand, this problem does not occur if i change the value of the other column (which is not in the group by box). 
The problem occurs only if i group a column and change its value not otherwise.
Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The code sample you have provided...

In which grid event do you have this code?
CellValueChanged or CellEdited or something else?

You may want to try these 3 lines instead of the single final line in your code sample:

```
   row.BeginEdit()
   drCurrent.Item(e.Column.DataMember) = value 'set the parent row column value
   row.EndEdit()
```

If that doesn't help, please provide more information about the other grid events you are using.